# creating new column by counting instances

Tags: excel, csv

I have a date column in the csv files as below.
I want to get another column that has the total number of rows for each dates. i.e Column_2 should have 4 for date 2/3/11,  2 for 2/4/11 & 1 for 2/5/11

Can I do this in excel?

```
    Col_1
   2/3/11 
   2/3/11 
   2/3/11 
   2/3/11 
   2/4/11 
   2/4/11 
   2/5/11
```

I do not want a count on each row, a count on the final instance of a repeating date is fine.

Comment: Yes you can do this easily in Excel, but to clarify, you have 4 rows of 2/3/11, so you want Col_2 to list "4" next to all 4 of them??

Comment: Are Col_1 and Col_2 actually called `A` and `B`?

Comment: no, but I can do that